# Excel formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im trying figure out, why functional formula work in excel and cant be simply added to VBA

```
Sub btn_Get_Type_Click()

    Dim lr As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E2:E" & lr) = "=IF(D2>0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(CORPORAT!A1:E30,5)),'CORPORATE','FIRM'),'HUMAN')"

    End With
End Sub
```

Any idea ? or im completly at wrong way?

Comment: Note that `Rows.Count` needs to be `.Rows.Count` with a dot in the beginning. Otherwise there is a possibility that this code fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What formula do you want to create?

Right now the answer is that your `MATCH` function won't work since you don't provide a searchcriteria and also `5` is no valid choice. `-1` (Less than), `0' (Exact) or`1` (greater than) are.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a problem with quotes. Try this:

```
Sub btn_Get_Type_Click()

    Dim lr As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E2:E" & lr) = .Range("E2:E" & lr) = "=IF(D2>0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(corporat!A1:E30,5)),""CORPORATE"",""FIRM""),""HUMAN"")"


    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I also think the `MATCH(corporat!A1:E30,5)` is wrong because it is `MATCH(search_criteria,search_matrix,compare_type)` so it should probably be the other way round `MATCH(5, corporat!A1:E30)` and the OP should chose a `compare_type` and add it too.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution, many thanks for advice. First was wrong .Rows.Count without dot, next MATCH without criteria and @JvdV tip and last one type Type mismatch, ", and ;" need to be only one type i quess.

this formula work:

```
    Sub btn_Get_Type_Click()

    Dim lr As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("E2:E" & lr) = "=IF(D2>0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,CORPORAT!$E$1:$E$30,0)),""K"",""PO""),""FO"")"


    End With
End Sub
```